# Using an L298N driver together with servo motors on the same arduino

Tags: arduino-mega, arduino-motor-shield, l298n

I'm using an L298N driver (powered by a 12V, 1.5A adapter) on a MEGA Sensor Shield (powered by a USB cable). Everything works fine and I can control the direction and the speed of the DC motor, however when I activate anything else on the shield - the motor will not spin unless I set the PWM to its highest frequency.

Please note that I am using Max/MSP to controls the motors, so when I say activate - I mean setting up the PinMode of pin 17 to "Servo". If I set up the Servo first and then the DC motor pins - it will again start spinning only at maximum PWM, there's no signal reaching the driver otherwise.

Am I missing something in my setup? I would use Arduino Mega on its own, however I need to use over 25 Servo motors together with the L298N driver, which makes the sensor shield inevitable.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue is with the fact that PWM is only supported on pins 2-13, so I shouldn't have connected it to pin 46.